# How can decrease the runtime for my program?

Tags: python, recursion, runtime

The program is taking a few minutes whenever I try to run it. The `cycle_length` refers to the Collatz cycle-length (the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) claims that, no matter what number you start with, you will always eventually reach `1` if you carry out a given calculation). The `max_length` computes the cycle length for integers between and including `i` and `j` to determine which number produces the longest cycle.

```
def cycle_length(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n    
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return cycle_length(n//2) + 1
    else:
        return cycle_length(3*n + 1) + 1

def max_length(i,j):
    mxl = cycle_length(i)
    mxn = i
    while i <= j:
        start = time.time()
        y = cycle_length(i)
        if y > mxl:
            mxl = y
            mxn = i
        i += 1
    return (mxn,mxl)

print(max_length(1, 10**6))
```

I want to iterate the program from `1` to `10**6`. Is there any effective way to make the program faster (under 10s)?

Answer (score 0):

The Collatz sequence is a really good opportunity to use [*"dynamic programming"* techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). The length of the sequence from a given number `n` will always be the same, so you can store that result and use it whenever you reach `n` again in some future sequence. For example, using a decorator to [*"memoize"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the result:

```
def memo(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in wrapper.cache:
            wrapper.cache[args] = func(*args)
        return wrapper.cache[args]
    wrapper.cache = {}
    return wrapper

@memo
def collatz_length(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n % 2:
        return 1 + collatz_length((3 * n) + 1)
    return 1 + collatz_length(n // 2)
```

Now if we run the program for a few starting values of `n`, you can see the `cache` gets filled with the pre-calculated results, speeding up future calls (at the expense of storage space - a classic programming trade-off):

```
>>> for x in range(1, 11):
    print x, collatz_length(x)


1 1
2 2
3 8
4 3
5 6
6 9
7 17
8 4
9 20
10 7
>>> collatz_length.cache
{(34,): 14, (9,): 20, (11,): 15, (13,): 10, (26,): 11, (1,): 1, (28,): 19 
 (3,): 8, (5,): 6, (16,): 5, (7,): 17, (20,): 8, (22,): 16, (8,): 4, (10,): 7,
 (14,): 18, (52,): 12, (2,): 2, (40,): 9, (4,): 3, (6,): 9, (17,): 13}
```

This can give you the result in about 1.5s:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('max(collatz_length(x+1) for x in range(10**6))',
           setup='from __main__ import collatz_length',
           number=1)
1.5072860717773438
```

Comment: You might find    `return cycle_length((n * 3) + 1 if n & 1 else n // 2) + 1`  is a little faster.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham perhaps, but I didn't want to stray too far from the OP's original implementation - I think this introduces enough new ideas already!

Answer (score 0):

You do a lot of time a same computation. To avoid this, we could store the values:

```
cache = {1 : 1}

def cycle_length(n):
    if n in cache.keys():
        return cache[n]
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        x = cycle_length(n//2) + 1
    else:
        x = cycle_length(3*n + 1) + 1
    cache[n] = x
    return x

def max_length(i,j):
    mxl = cycle_length(i)
    mxn = i
    while i <= j:
        y = cycle_length(i)
        if y > mxl:
            mxl = y
            mxn = i
        i += 1
    return (mxn,mxl)

print(max_length(1, 10**6))
```

On my machine, your code ran in 29.9 seconds. My code gives the same result and run in 1.8 seconds.

---

EDIT: I wrote a script to compare the efficiency of the 3 answers.

```
from functools import lru_cache
import time

cache = {1 : 1}
def cycle_length1(n):
    if n in cache.keys():
        return cache[n]
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        x = cycle_length1(n//2) + 1
    else:
        x = cycle_length1(3*n + 1) + 1
    cache[n] = x
    return x

def memo(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in wrapper.cache:
            wrapper.cache[args] = func(*args)
        return wrapper.cache[args]
    wrapper.cache = {}
    return wrapper

@memo
def cycle_length2(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n % 2:
        return 1 + cycle_length2((3 * n) + 1)
    return 1 + cycle_length2(n // 2)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def cycle_length3(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return cycle_length3(n//2) + 1
    else:
        return cycle_length3(3*n + 1) + 1

def max_length(f, i=1, j=10**6):
    mxl = f(i)
    mxn = i
    while i <= j:
        y = f(i)
        if y > mxl:
            mxl = y
            mxn = i
        i += 1
    return (mxn,mxl)

for f in [cycle_length1, cycle_length2, cycle_length3]:
    tic = time.time()
    print(max_length(f))
    print("%s\n" % (time.time() - tic))
```

Result:

```
(837799, 525)
1.5899293422698975

(837799, 525)
4.623902320861816

(837799, 525)
4.403488874435425
```

It seems that this answer is the most efficient (I think there is a smaller overhead, we manipulate a simple dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to memoize the values  of the `cycle_length`. If you are indeed using Python 3 (3.3+), you can just decorate your function `cycle_length` with the `lru_cache(maxsize=None)`; this program has runtime of 5 seconds on my laptop:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def cycle_length(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n    
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return cycle_length(n//2) + 1
    else:
        return cycle_length(3*n + 1) + 1

def max_length(i,j):
    mxl = cycle_length(i)
    mxn = i
    while i <= j:
        start = time.time()
        y = cycle_length(i)
        if y > mxl:
            mxl = y
            mxn = i
        i += 1
    return (mxn,mxl)

print(max_length(1, 10**6))
```